# Withholding Tax for Citizen of No Tax Treaty with US

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, withholding, form-w-8-ben

I am a citizen and resident of Saudi Arabia, a country with no tax treaty with the US. I receive monthly royalties from Amazon as a designer in their print on demand platform (they sell t shirts of my designs) and they withhold 30% of the royalties. Is there any way I can get tax exemption or reduction on my royalties?

I was looking at applying for an ITIN or using form W-8BEN to request exemption but I have no idea if this will work at all.